# запустить winrar и дождаться завершения в java

Tags: java

Необходимо разархивировать каталог, и после того как все файлы разархивируются, продолжить работу.
Вызываю rar так

```
Process proc1 = Runtime.getRuntime()
                   .exec("d:/temp/rar.exe x d:/temp/folder.rar d:/temp");
```

После вызова выполнение программы идет дальше, а разархивирование идет параллельно.
Необходимо не выполнять программу дальше, пока rar не закончит.

Answer (score 1):

```
Process proc1 = Runtime.getRuntime()
               .exec("cmd /c start /wait d:/temp/rar.exe x d:/temp/folder.rar d:/temp");
proc1.waitFor();
//дальше продолжаем
```

Comment: Так действительно работает. Только появляется окно консоли в которой работает rar. Как его скрыть? /b я добавлял, перестает работать. Видимо если нет консоли, то программа считает что процесс завершился.

Comment: Попробуйте без `start`

Comment: Не работает без старт. Можно конечно громоздко считать количество файлов в новой дирректории. Делать паузу и опять считать. Потом сравнивать, увеличивается количество или нет. Как перестанет увеличиваться то процесс завешился